# Array map using Microsoft excel to program a rpg game

Tags: java, arrays, maps

Hello this is my second year of doing java in school. Ive been having many difficulties understanding what are arrays, and how to use arrays to make a map in a rpg game . I must use microsoft excel in order to make the map. To be more specific i want to make a basic street fighter game but i need to learn the basic skeleton of making a maps for my game. If someone could help me that would be great thanks again. I am using java.

Comment: what does excel have to do w/ making the map?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the standard way to do this in school is actually reading/writing to a txt-file. 
Are you sure you are not talking about a .txt file?

You probably want to load the map via a

```
 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(Filename));
```

Comment: yes you are correct, i am asked to use microsoft excel to make the map using numbers to repersent the graphics i want to import

Answer (score 0):

For a very simple map, if you must use arrays, you can think of it as a simple X,Y coordinate maze.  Let's say the origin of the maze is in the upper-left corner.

```
[0,0] [1,0] [2,0]
[0,1] [1,1] [2,1]
[0,2] [1,2] [2,2]
```

In your spreadsheet, you could a unique name of each room in each cell coordinate.  So cell A1 represents [0,0].  Cell B1 represents [1,0] and so forth.  Save that file in CSV format.

Let us presume that the maze is a perfect square (same number of X and Y coordinates).  Write Java code to load that CSV file.  When you read the first row of the CSV file, that will tell you the size of the two-dimensional array to create:

```
String[][] rooms = new String[ numberOfColumns ][ numberOfColumns ];
```

At that point, you read each row, and populate each coordinate of the string array with the appropriate value in the CSV file.

After that, you now have a two-dimensional array of rooms.  You can then create logic to allow your player to move from room to room within the array.  Just keep track of the player's current X,Y position.  Make sure you check to ensure that the player's coordinates cannot be less than zero or greater than the size of the maze.

Hope that helps.